# Lightbox works but not when uploaded to the server

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, lightbox

I have had a good look at previous questions/answers to this but am a newbie.
Have downloaded Firebug - Do not particularly understand.

http://www.deccardy.com/portfolio-field-house.html

Is the page I am trying to sort out with Lightbox.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Also, if you know of a way of lightbox ordering the images, say #1 - #5 - #2 - #6 as opposed in sequence, this would be great!

Many thanks,

Cody

Comment: to get you started, fix the following :

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.deccardy.com/effects.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.deccardy.com/builder.js

Comment: These files are now uploaded...

Answer (score 1):

You have 404 errors on page, that's why script is failing.

```
404 Not Found:
http://www.deccardy.com/effects.js
http://www.deccardy.com/builder.js
```

Comment: @user1685596 404 Not Found: `http://www.deccardy.com/closelabel.gif` and `http://www.deccardy.com/loading.gif`. Now it opens in the left after click on image.

Answer (score 1):

The below mentioned files are not publicly accessible. Upload both the JS Files.

```
http://www.deccardy.com/effects.js
http://www.deccardy.com/builder.js
```

Get them from [here](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the **`lightbox.css`** too. The lightbox works on script-side(you'll see it when you scroll to the bottom of the page), but without the css-file it's not the desired result.

But however: I would suggest an update to the current Version(which uses jQuery).

Comment: This file is on the server - Tho' didn't understand the last part of your comment?

Comment: The file may be on the server, but you did not load it anywhere. When you mean this file: http://www.deccardy.com/lightbox.css , this is not the correct css for your lightbox-version. Use this: http://pastebin.com/BCANg4BG

Comment: Many thanks to y'all - Any idea as to how to change sequence/order images are shown in - This is a small part but will mean I don't have to manually re-oder other portfolio pages!!